# I want to check if an element has a specific class name that is inside other elements

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have in my application multiple table-rows and want to delete one of them.
i have a function that when i click on a button another table-row is made.

first i have:

```
<table>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id='firstObject'> <td> <i class="icon-chevron-right clickable expand-alert"></i> </td> <td> @Ajax.RawActionLink("<i class='icon-trash'></i>", "_DeleteAlert", "Group", new { alertId = alert.Id }, new AjaxOptions
    {
         HttpMethod = "POST",
         OnSuccess = "onDeleteAlertSuccess(" + alert.Id + ")"
    }, new { @title = "Verwijder alarm" }) </td> </tr>
    <tr id='secondObject'> <td> <i class="icon-chevron-right clickable expand-alert"></i> </td> <td> @Ajax.RawActionLink("<i class='icon-trash'></i>", "_DeleteAlert", "Group", new { alertId = alert.Id }, new AjaxOptions
    {
         HttpMethod = "POST",
         OnSuccess = "onDeleteAlertSuccess(" + alert.Id + ")"
    }, new { @title = "Verwijder alarm" }) </td> </tr> ....
```

But if i click on the `i` the class `icon-chevron-right` becomes `icon-chevron-down` and i get:

```
<tbody>
<tr id='firstObject'> <td> <i class="icon-chevron-down clickable expand-alert"></i> </td> <td> @Ajax.RawActionLink("<i class='icon-trash'></i>", "_DeleteAlert", "Group", new { alertId = alert.Id }, new AjaxOptions
    {
         HttpMethod = "POST",
         OnSuccess = "onDeleteAlertSuccess(" + alert.Id + ")"
    }, new { @title = "Verwijder alarm" }) </td> </tr>
<tr id='info'> ... </tr>
<tr id='secondObject'> <td> <i class="icon-chevron-right clickable expand-alert"></i> </td> <td> @Ajax.RawActionLink("<i class='icon-trash'></i>", "_DeleteAlert", "Group", new { alertId = alert.Id }, new AjaxOptions
    {
         HttpMethod = "POST",
         OnSuccess = "onDeleteAlertSuccess(" + alert.Id + ")"
    }, new { @title = "Verwijder alarm" }) </td> </tr> ....
```

No comes the trick. If i click on the DeleteButton i want to delete that row and if `$(i).hasClass('icon-chevron-down')` delete also the next row which is the row with `id='info'`. I my code the tr's doesn't have an id this is just to explain it better.

Here's my function:

```
    function onDeleteAlertSuccess(id) {
        $('#alert-detail-table').find('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
                $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    if ($(this).next($('td').next($('i').hasClass('icon-chevron-down')))) {
                        $(this).next('tr').remove();
                    }
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The second if is always true, but it must be false if `!$('i').hasClass('icon-chevron-down')`. Now it removes, if `id='icon-chevron-right'`, the next table-row with `id='secondObject'` and that isn't right.

How do i solve this problem?

EDIT:

I solved the problem with help from Jérémy:

```
    function onDeleteAlertSuccess(id) {
        $('#alert-detail-table').find('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
                $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    var tr = $(this);
                    var nextElement = tr.next();

                    tr.find("i").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).hasClass("icon-chevron-down")) {
                            nextElement.remove();
                        }
                    });
                    //if ($(this).first($('td:first-child').hasClass('icon-chevron-down'))) {
                    //    debugger;
                    //}
                    //if ($(this).next($('td').next($('i').hasClass('icon-chevron-down')))) {
                    //    $(this).next('tr').remove();
                    //}
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML and JS seem not related.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity and your code does little in the way of explaining the situation for us.

Comment: Sorry @ShivanRaptor i have edited my question. They were linked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You codes are not linked, as said Shivan in a comment, but I still tryed to do something with it. If I understand well, clicking on a delete button should remove the linked row, and the row after if some class is defined in it.

So I made a little fiddle, showing how to do that easily with jQuery : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kj7Q2/)

```
$( function() {
    $( document ).on( "click", ".deleteLink", function() {
        var tr = $( this ).parent().parent();
        var nextElement = tr.next();

        if( nextElement.hasClass( "notLink" ) ) {
            nextElement.remove();    
        }

        tr.remove();

        return false;
    });
});
```

`notLink` is the class of a tr that should be removed by it's upper row, and `deleteLink` is the class for your delete buttons

EDIT :

If the class is on the `i` element, and not in the `tr`, then it is also simple to check it ; please see [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kj7Q2/1/) and code corresponding :

```
$( function() {
    $( document ).on( "click", ".deleteLink", function() {
        var tr = $( this ).parent().parent();
        var nextElement = tr.next();

        nextElement.find( "i" ).each( function() {
            if( $( this ).hasClass( "toRemove" ) ) {
                nextElement.remove();   
            }
        });

        tr.remove();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I still can't understand your question... Where does the `i` comes from ? If you want to remove the next element according to a condition, it's what my function does with `nextElement` and `hasClass` statement

Comment: Just launch a fiddle and show us your actual code, that we could understand and maybe debug it

Comment: the `i` is in `@Ajax.RawActionLink`

Comment: Please put the **generated** HTML, instead of the source code you write, it would be easier to solve your problem ;)

Comment: I hope you understand my question now!

Comment: Yep, the classes were to be replaced ;) Don't forget to select the answer if it helped you ;)